# How can i add my app to ARC runtime?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

If I install any launcher app on ARC welder app, I can see two apps gallery and contacts. Like that i want to add my app also with them. I am able to build ARC runtime on ubuntu and we have no problem with distributing our custom ARC runtime.

Any idea how can i add my app to ARC runtime like gallery and contacts?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't.

We have apps for the gallery and contacts supplied as part of the ARC runtime only so that they can handle intents around those features, so apps that expect to access the gallery and contacts work.

We would expect to bundle more apps like this only if there was a fairly universal need for an app to act as a compatability layer between the ARC and the apps you develop.